# How we store weblist element into array using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

How we store web list element into array using Selenium WebDriver

eg:

```
weblist.get(j).findElement(By.className("accordion-toggle")).getText()
```

It contains list of element how we store that elements into array.

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this

```
    //to catch all web elements into list
    List<WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.className("accordion-toggle"));

    //myList contains all the web elements
    //if you want to get all elements text into array list
    List<String> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){

        //loading text of each element in to array all_elements_text
        all_elements_text.add(myList.get(i).getText());

        //to print directly
        System.out.println(myList.get(i).getText());

    }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

using weblist.size() helps when the end result it unknown. Thus help us create array list, without giving a definite end.

```
for(j=0;j<weblist.size();J++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the number of elements in the list, use Java's List interface:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(j=0;j<weblist.size();J++){  
  list.add(weblist.get(j).findElement(By.className("accordion-toggle")).getText())
}
```

Comment: Why not `list.size()` ? instead of N.

Comment: @guy, you are right.`weblist.size()` can replace `N`. The code part posted in question is not complete, so I didn't want to make more assumptions. updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `findElement` you have to use `findElements` method of selenium webdriver. It will directly return list of web elements. To use By functionality of selenium create custom method getBy which will use By abstract class.

```
public List<WebElement> findElements(String locator, long... timeOut) {
    try {
        if (timeOut.length == 1 && timeOut[0] == 0) {
            return driver.findElements(getBy(locator));
        } else if (timeOut.length == 1 && timeOut[0] > 0) {
            waitForPresent(locator, timeOut[0]);
        } else {
            waitForPresent(locator);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return driver.findElements(getBy(locator));
}

String xPath = "xpath=//*[@text='some text']";
//String xPath = "name='some text'";
//String xPath = "id=xxxx";

private By getBy(String locator) {
    locator = getProps().getString(locator, locator);
    String[] parts = locator.split("=", 2);
    By by = null;
    switch (parts[0].trim()) {
    case "xpath":
        by = By.xpath(parts[1]);
        break;
    case "name":
        by = By.name(parts[1]);
        break;
    case "link":
        by = By.linkText(parts[1]);
        break;
    case "id":
        by = By.id(parts[1]);
        break;
    case "css":
        by = By.cssSelector(parts[1]);
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("invalid locator");
    }
    return by;
}
```